# Mips to binary and starting address

Tags: mips

I have this statement

```
addiu $v0, $zero, 0
```

That is I type

opcode is 001001

rs is 00000
rt is 00002

Function is 0000 0000 0000 0000

So all together it's `0010 0100 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000`

So in hex that's

0x24020000

The problem is, is that it says: It is loaded into memory at address 0x00080000 .

How do i account for the loaded memory address?

Answer (score 1):

`0x24020000` is an instruction, it has nothing to do with PC, in your case, `0x00080000`.
The memory address mapping is normally done in link stage.

Comment: are you sure? why would they give me that info though? "The program below is written using the MIPS instruction set. It is loaded into memory at address 0x00080000 (starting with ‘code’)" Write out the number (in decimal) for each field (opcode, rs, rt etc) and the final bits representation in Hex.  (Be sure to put down all your steps for partial credit in case you make some mistake at any steps)